# copy files from list but skip if the file does not exist with shutil copy and multiprocessing

Tags: python, copy

I am trying to copy files from a directory based on a list of file names. The code is working fine as long as the file from the list exists in the directory, but if it does not the process will stop and I get the error: No such file or directory

I would like the process to proceed to the next file if it doesnt find the file from the list in the directory. Any ideas how I can achieve this?

This is my code:

```
# Import libraries
import pandas as pd
import shutil
import os
import subprocess
from joblib import Parallel, delayed
import multiprocessing

# define how many cores should be used
num_cores = 30 

os.chdir(source_folder)
# start to copy the tif images to the local drive
tmp = Parallel(n_jobs=num_cores)(delayed(shutil.copy)(f, dst_folder) for f in source_files_list)
```

cheers!

Comment: I'd build my source_files list based on ```os.path.exists``` condition

Comment: Just do `... for f in source_files_list if os.path.exists(f))`